# How can I ask users just one question?

Tags: usability-testing, question-answer

I need to ask users just one question on our website - namely "Did you find what you were looking for?" as an exit question.

This is just one question that requires a high confidence level of data i.e. 90% of users agreed that there are enough products on the site, 10% couldn't find what they were looking for etc.

How can I best ask this question to users to get a good  response rate? Twitter? Qualaroo? (Expensive)? Build own questionnaire pop-up when users leave the site? What Users Do?

*more information*
The website is an ecommerce site that sells a particular product. We believe that the lack of product range on the site is restrictive for users buying. Longer time spent on category pages and, indeed, switching from category to category certainly suggest this. But what we're asking for here is a little bit in-quantifiable. Don't you agree? (I could re-phrase the question to be more "how do I determine whether there is enough product range on my site" rather than provide an answer)

Comment: You'll never get a high degree of confidence with a question on a website like this. Regardless of how you word it or display it it's up to the visitor to interact with it as they see fit - ignore, click first button they see, close whole tab... Also, you may only get people who feel strongly in one particular way answering (so you end up with 90% of people who answer it clicking No, even though that's just 1% of the actual audience). Your best bet is to use internal analytics to find out. Did they spend x time on the page? Did they go elsewhere afterwards? Use real data to determine site use.

Comment: @JonW This comment should definitely be an answer :)

Comment: @Franchesca: Thanks, but I didn't really give an answer to his question, I just gave a different way of thinking of the issue itself. If it's a business requirement that this question exists then my comment isn't really much use there.

Comment: I have added more context to the question to help you understand the business requirement

Comment: @DLM - I think what JonW is trying to get at is that the business requirement doesn't matter - the users don't care about your business requirements. ESPECIALLY if they haven't found what they are after, they aren't going to be inclined to answer your questions. Trying to get info directly from them is just going to make them mad, not get you what you need. You need to find a way to answer your questions WITHOUT asking the user anything directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look to some services that try to detect when a user is going to leave a site, based on their actions or elements they click on, to try and prompt when to pose your question on your site.

Another thing to consider is using analytics to identify your target demographic and do some surveying. Send out emails to customers looking for their feedback. Incentivizing this with a possible discount (since you said it was ecommerce ) could raise response rates, coupled with a secondary push to social media with a CTA to have the chance to give feedback to the company. Also, do you have analytics on where users are going in your site, how long they stay on pages? Are you looking to put more products simply to put more products, or as a company are you trying to expand your service offering? Whats the goal by asking this question and how does that relate to what can be measured?

Lastly you could try to sign-up with testing sites that put users through your site and have them give feedback based on questions you set up. This might be expensive and a little too broad since you are looking at one aspect of your site in particular, but if there are other things you'd like to gather for feedback then something to consider.